# Determine wether $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3n-1}{(n+1)^3}$ converges or diverges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Determine wether the following function converges or diverges by comparison test: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3n-1}{(n+1)^3}$

Upon inspection I can clearly see that the series converges. However I am unsure how to know which series I can compare the series above with the prove this. Can someone tell me which series they would use and how they decided upon that?

Thank you soo much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{3n-1}{(n+1)^3}\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{3n}{(n+1)^3}\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{3n}{n^3}=3\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}<\infty.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{3n-1}{(n+1)^3} = 3\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}-4\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(n+1)^3} = 3(\zeta(2)-1)-4(\zeta(3)-1) = \color{red}{3\zeta(2)-4\zeta(3)+1}.$$